# Corrupted FormRequest with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am starting with a simple request, and when I get the callback, `pre_results` in this case, I want to send out `x` number of POST-requests to a form to get out all the information possible. When I am sending the requests, it sends the same request each time.

I know that the url is correct, the `value`s are correct. It looks like the for-loop somehow is corrupting the requests. Isn't it possible to send out multiple `FormRequest`s from a custom parse method in `scrapy`? I have tried with delays up to 10 seconds, still no luck.

```
def pre_results(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    log.msg("Refining results with number %d and url %s" % (response.meta['item']['number'], response.url), log.INFO)
    minurl = response.url.replace("results", "refine_results")
    requests = []
    for value in hxs.select('//select[@id="profile_electricity_plan_type"]/option/@value').extract():
    request = FormRequest(url=minurl,
                          formdata={'profile[electricity_plan_type]' : value}, #This value is correct
                          callback=self.step_results,
                          dont_filter=True) # To be able to send to the same URL
        request.meta['item'] = response.meta['item']
        request.meta['item']['company'] = value
        yield request
```

If anyone have some input, I greatly appreciate it.
Thanks

**EDIT**:
It sends out X requests with the same value being the last one of the value it's iterating over. At least when it hits `self.step_results` it's all the same.

Comment: Are you sure that you are getting different `value`s in the loop? Plus, do you see different `value`s in `step_results` method while accessing `response.meta['item']['company']`?

Comment: That is the weird part. I've logged the values in the loop, and it has the right values. I have even logged request.meta['item']['company'] with success. When the responses appears in self.step_results, they all have the same value.

Comment: Ok, then how do you check `value`s in `self.step_results`?

Comment: Exactly like you said.

Comment: could you please comment out `request.meta['item'] = response.meta['item']` and replace `request.meta['item']['company'] = value` with `request.meta['test'] = value`? See what is printed in `step_results` while executing `print response.meta['test']`?

Comment: Oh, of course that worked. That's a stupid approach, I'm always changing the outgoing request. It still doesn't solve my initial problem though, but thanks for pointing that out.